# Modularization of a Java 17 project: compilation warns me against Invalid module names of third parties jars. Will this prevent me from succeed?

Tags: java, module

I'm starting my project modularization.

This way, I expect getting rid of boring `--add-exports`, `--add-opens` declarations I have everywhere around `java` commands in command lines scripts, *Maven* POM, service of `systemctl` declaration.

```
--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
```

And it's also a good time for cleaning POMs from excessive dependencies.

---

But as soon I've wrote my first `modules.java` file for my first component (among 54),
*Maven* handles it and *Java* compilation warns me against some
**invalid module names**
that can be found among third parties dependencies (here, from a parent POM).

```
Can't extract module name from kafka_2.13-3.1.2-test.jar: kafka.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
Can't extract module name from jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.5.jar: jackson.module.scala.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
Can't extract module name from scala-logging_2.13-3.9.3.jar: scala.logging.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
Can't extract module name from kafka_2.13-3.1.2.jar: kafka.2.13: Invalid module name: '2' is not a Java identifier
```

Does this mean I am doomed, and eventually these jars will prevent modularization,
or do I have a way to workaround them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those libraries don't have a `module-info.class`, nor do they have an `Automatic-Module-Name` entry in their manifest, so Java uses a heuristic to derive a module name from the JAR filename. This heuristic fails and results in an invalid name.

You have two choices:

1. Don't try to use these libraries as modules, but add them to the classpath instead of the modulepath; this will make them part of the unnamed module. Your modular code will not be able to interact with them directly. Only non-modularized code (JARs without a `module-info.class`) on the modulepath can directly interact with classes on the classpath. So, maybe it is a sign you shouldn't attempt to modularize this application.
2. You will either need to manually patch those libraries so at minimum they declare an `Automatic-Module-Name` in their manifest, or contain a `module-info.class`, or you need to look for a version which is either properly modularized, or at least declares the `Automatic-Module-Name` (FYI, even Kafka 3.5.0 doesn't have this yet). Alternatively, rename the libraries on your deployment so they don't break the derivation of module names (specifically, remove the `-2.13` of the Scala version, and maybe the `-test` suffix needs to come before the version).

There is an open issue on the Kafka project requesting addition of an `Automatic-Module-Name`, [KAFKA-7490](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7490), but given it has been open since 2018, I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for it.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to accomplish 1 with a maven setup?